# Align horizontally element in the header page

Tags: html, css, flexbox, angular-material

I use angular material and css style to align my element of header page. I want to align the three icons (settings, help_outline and person_outline ) right.

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="toggleSideBar()">
            <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>

        <span> APP LOGO </span>

        <div fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="flex-end">
            <ul fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px" style="display: flex; align-items: flex-end;">
                <li>
                    <button mat-icon-button>
                        <mat-icon>settings</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button mat-icon-button>
                        <mat-icon>help_outline</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
                        <mat-icon>person_outline</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
                        <button mat-menu-item>
                            <mat-icon>exit_to_app</mat-icon>
                            Sign out
                        </button>
                    </mat-menu>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

[image]
Any idea to do this?

Comment: Did you try `float:right` to pull them to right? add it to icons' parent div to pull them all at once.

Comment: hello @oguzhancerit, i put float:right but nothing changes. can you show your idea with simple code example

Comment: if you share working sample i can help more

Comment: Please show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you.

Comment: Hello @oguzhancerit , see the link where you can see my work https://stackblitz.com/github/lnquaidorsay/bibliofront

Answer (score 1):

```css
mat-toolbar-row{
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

div {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<mat-toolbar>
  <mat-toolbar-row>
  
    <div id="menu">
      <button>
            <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
      <span> APP LOGO </span>
    </div>
  
    <div id="icons">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <button mat-icon-button>
            <mat-icon>settings</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button mat-icon-button>
            <mat-icon>help_outline</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button>
            <mat-icon>person_outline</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

I'm sure there are many other ways to do it as well.

Answer (score 0):

To align the icons, you have simple options

1. separate the content of your toolbar in well difined groups (left, center right) and define the `justify-content` property of `mat-toolbar` to `space-between`. It will align said grups with automatic spacing between groups.
2. Use a spacer just as especified in the documentation. Just create an empty `span` between your logo and your icons group and define the `flex` property of said span to `1 1 auto`. It will span the element to take whatever space is available, pushing your icons to the right.
3. Even simpler, use `margin-left: auto` on your icons group would do the trick.

Checkout the examples in the documentation, in doubt inspect the code and see the span trick they used: https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/examples